# HDD keeps respinning when idle on power save mode on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, power

I have recently got a new PC, and I just noticed that *when on power saving mode*, and *when the PC is idle so that the screen turns off*, the HDD keeps respinning all time.

It stops spinning, spins again, stops, spins, etc., as fast as it could. (I hear it)

When I touch the keyboard or mouse to light up the screen, the HDD gets back normal (spinning all time)

Is this is a power saving feature or something to worry about? I really doubt respinning the drive is good for its health.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure it's the hard drive it could be an idle Antivirus scan or the computer might be set up to index the hard drive for faster searches.

In **Windows 10** you can click the windows key and route indexing options. Maybe disabling that or AV temporarily to see if it stops will help troubleshoot it. I suggest disconnecting from the network if you disable AV.